# Printing Cross Compiled libraries(C/C++) Log (printf) in Android (Logcat)

Tags: c++, c, android-studio, android-logcat

I cross compiled some C/C++ libraries using Netbeans for android. Those libraries have `log` information, which i want to see while the application run on the phone. is there any way, that those `log` information present in C/C++ cross compiled static libs can be displayed on `logcat` or anywhere else in Android studio.